# React - Redux connect()() syntax clarity

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

I have just started to learn react-redux and got confused with syntax specified in connect function of redux.

From my understanding the normal function  we define  and call as follows:

```
//function definition
function fun_name(arg){
    //do some operations
}


// function calling
fun_name('my_argument');
```

In react found some interesting line

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)('SomeComponentName');
```

But here the above line calling connect function with two arguments mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps.
And latter it defined ('SomeComponentName')

**Does any one know what kind of syntax is "connect()()" or it is part of export ?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is called **currying** in JS.

Currying is a transformation of functions that translates a function from callable as f(a, b, c) into callable as f(a)(b)(c).

Currying doesn’t call a function. It just transforms it.

source https://javascript.info/currying-partials

e.g

```js
function outer(){
  return inner
}

function inner(){
 console.log("I got called")
}

outer()()
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, connect is a method which returns another method.

So, when you do `connect()`, it calls the connect method and returns a method which is called by the second `()` when you do `connect()()`.

Comment: do you have any reference or link that I can check?

Answer (score 1):

The `connect()` function returns another function which needs to be called and requires a parameter which is the component.

As [`connect()` Returns](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#connect-returns) documentation states:

> The return of connect() is a wrapper function that takes your component and returns a wrapper component with the additional props it injects. In most cases, the wrapper function will be called right away, without being saved in a temporary variable: `export default connect(mapState, mapDispatch)(Login)`.

You can think about like the following code snippet:

```
const connectedFunction = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps);
export default connectedFunction(SomeComponentName);
```

Suggested read for `connect()` overview: https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#overview

I hope that helps!